# How to solve quadratically constrained linear program in R with clarabel

Tags: r, optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm looking for some help converting a quadratic constraint into the form needed for the clarabel optimization package (second-order cone programming solver).

Firstly, here is just the linear part of the problem:

```
library(clarabel)
library(Matrix)

a = c(1.425, 0.27, -0.085, -0.733, -0.534, 1.402, -0.199, -0.875, -1.586, -2.126)
xl = rep(0, 10)
xu = rep(1, 10)
A = rbind(rep(1, 10), Diagonal(10), -Diagonal(10))
b = c(1, xu, -xl)

x = clarabel(A, b, -a, cones=list(z=1, l=20))$x
```

And here is test data for the quadratic constraint:

```
y = c(0.242, 0.058, 0.204, 0.112, 0.123, 0.143, 0, 0.065, 0, 0.053)
Q = structure(c(1.291, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.018, 0.525, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.034, 0.02, 0.543, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0.012, 0.011, 0.015, 0.536, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.039, 0.021, 0.036,
                0.012, 0.874, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.064, 0.02, 0.046, 0.009, 0.054,
                0.735, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.007, 0.019, 0.001, 0.025, 0.035, 1.791,
                0, 0, 0, 0.031, 0.018, 0.029, 0.011, 0.032, 0.043, 0.03, 1.242,
                0, 0, 0.008, 0.008, 0.012, 0.045, 0.006, 0.004, 0.008, 0.007,
                0.55, 0, 0.005, 0.007, 0.009, 0.041, 0.003, 0, 0.01, 0.006, 0.062,
                0.479), .Dim = c(10L, 10L))
Q = as(as(Q + lower.tri(Q) * t(Q), 'CsparseMatrix'), 'symmetricMatrix')
```

The quadratic constraint I'm trying to impose is `sqrt((x-y) %*% Q %*% (x-y)) <= 0.1`, which is equivalent to `x %*% Q %*% x - 2 * x %*% Q %*% y - (0.1^2 - y %*% Q %*% y) <= 0`.

By putting the quadratic term in the objective, I did a simple search to find the approximate solution to have a guide of what to expect:

```
lambda = 13.8703
x = clarabel(A, b, -a + lambda * -2 * drop(Q %*% y), 2 * lambda * Q, cones=list(z=1, l=20))$x
```

So far so good, but my attempts at following various guides on convert QCQP to SOCP (eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330896/can-a-convex-qcqp-with-an-additional-linear-constraint-be-converted-into-a-socp), or [here](https://au.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/convert-quadratic-constraints-to-second-order-cone-constraints.html)) either produce infeasible errors or seem to ignore the constraint entirely.

This is what I've tried (both infeasible):

```
S = chol(Q)
lin = drop(-2 * Q %*% y)
rhs = drop(0.1^2 - y %*% Q %*% y)
bb = -drop(solve(S, lin))
gamma = -sqrt(drop(crossprod(bb)) + rhs)

res = clarabel(rbind(A, 0, S), c(b, rhs, lin), -a, cones=list(z=1, l=20, q=11))
solver_status_descriptions()[res$status]

res = clarabel(rbind(A, 0, S), c(b, gamma, bb), -a, cones=list(z=1, l=20, q=11))
solver_status_descriptions()[res$status]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried installing `clarabel but got an error and the error msg said to run this `rustc --explain E0716`. Maybe there's a binary someplace?

Comment: Yes it is not so easy to install on linux unfortunately - I installed rust but it failed to build from source, I think because my R is too old. On windows the binary package works easily.

Comment: It failed to build for me as well in both on R 4.2.1 and R 4.3.1, so I put an issue up on the r-clarabel Github venue (as per the links in the DESCRIPTION file.) The authors responded almost immediately with a few changes to the rust code, and have a version 0.6.0 in the works. It hasn't migrated to CRAN or Github at least for the R package.

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM - that's great; I should be able to build it once I upgrade R (still using repo default 3.6). I've finally figured out the answer (on my windows box) - will post it below to hopefully help people stuck on QCQP conversion in future!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out my original attempt above was both incorrect in how it passed the cone parameters to clarabel, and also incorrect in that it requires a symmetric matrix square root (as per many of the QCQP to SOCP transformations). The below actually does successfully enforce the quadratic constraint:

```
S = as(expm::sqrtm(Q), 'sparseMatrix')
lin = -2 * drop(Q %*% y)
bb = 0.5*drop(solve(S, -lin))
target = 0.1^2 - drop(y %*% Q %*% y)
x = clarabel(rbind(A, -0.1, S), c(b, 0, bb), -a, cones=list(z=1, l=20, q=11))$x
sqrt((x - y) %*% Q %*% (x - y)) # => 0.1
```

Unfortunately in my real problem, I've got a very large sparse matrix, so I was looking for a transformation that just uses the Cholesky factorization. Using the above doesn't work due to the linear term, but that can be avoided by adding additional variables with equality constraints for the linear term (note change in A matrix and size of zero cone):

```
S = chol(Q)
A2 = rbind(cbind(Diagonal(10), -Diagonal(10)), cbind(A, Matrix(0, nrow(A), 10)))
b2 = c(y, b)
a2 = c(a, rep(0, 10))
x = clarabel(rbind(A2, c(rep(-0.1, 20)), cbind(Matrix(0, 10, 10), S)), c(b2, rep(0, 11)), -a2, cones=list(z=11, l=20, q=11))$x[1:10]
sqrt((x - y) %*% Q %*% (x - y)) # => 0.1
```

That was a bit unsatisfactory too though, as doubling the number of variables (and constraints) in my problem seems undesirable from a performance perspective. In the end I found a transformation [here](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/courses/310w13/socp.pdf) on page 9 that can work with a Cholesky factorization:

```
S = chol(Q)
lin = -2 * drop(Q %*% y)
target = 0.1^2 - drop(y %*% Q %*% y)
x = clarabel(rbind(A, lin/2, S, -lin/2), c(b, (1+target)/2, rep(0, 10), (1-target)/2), -a, cones=list(z=1, l=20, q=12))$x
sqrt((x - y) %*% Q %*% (x - y)) # => 0.1
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with cone spaces or algebras, but looking at that paper made me wonder if this was a problem in a Lorentz space, e.i. something involving special relativity.